# Receiver stopped receiving in Oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I understand services and such are being clamped down on, so my receiver has stopped working in Android Oreo.

I have this code starting the service -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("Time", locationUpdatesTime);
intent.putExtra("Dist", locationUpdatesDistance);
startService(intent);
```

I have this in my service -

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.androidandyuk.laptimerbuddy");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
intent.putExtra("Lat", thisLat);
intent.putExtra("Lon", thisLon);

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But my receiver is never called.  Having searched around I think I have to register my receiver, but I can't figure how I code this with the correct syntax. Can anyone help please?

If you wish to downvote me, I'd appreciate if you would comment why, so I can learn as I've looked for an answer, couldn't find/understand it and I think I've laid the question out as I should :-)

Many thanks!

**UPDATE** Trying to use a LocalBroadcastManager.

In MainActivity I have -

```
BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver;
```

onCreate I have -

```
mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            Log.i("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
```

In my service, onLocationChanged

```
    Log.i("sender", "Broadcasting message");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("custom-event-name");
                intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");

 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This works as I see the sender message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Manifest-registered receivers cannot receive broadcasts of implicit `Intents`. If your sender and receiver are in the same app and same process, stop using system broadcasts (`sendBroadcast()` and `registerReceiver()` on `Context`). Instead, use `LocalBroadcastManager`. Not only does this get you past the changes in Android 8.0, but it improves speed and security. But, as Code-Apprentice suggests, please show how you are registering this receiver.

Comment: I haven't registered the receiver before... I don't think?  But it worked before Oreo.  I'm trying to learn by following others code, so only gradually understanding what I'm doing you see.  I've tried to follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager but my service has no context, which I assume is why it doesn't work?

Comment: A `Service` is a `Context`. Do note that `LocalBroadcastManager` does not work across processes. If your `Service` is running in a separate process - i.e., if it has a `process` attribute on its `<service>` element in the manifest - that's not going to work. CommonsWare alludes to that above, but you might've missed it.

Comment: I've done this example - http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/localbroadcastmanager-intra-application.html  on it's own on Oreo and it works, so I'll try and replicate that into my app.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Since Android Oreo, receivers must be registered in runtime using context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter); to receive implicit intents

You can still receive explicit intents and some special implicit actions, as boot_completed or locale_changed for example

More information at https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts

Answer (score 2):

**create your intent than pass in method**

```
 sendImplicitBroadcast(this,new Intent(IntentActions.ACTION_APP_CREATE));
```

**Static Method**

```
public static void sendImplicitBroadcast(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
    PackageManager pm=ctxt.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> matches=pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(i, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : matches) {
        Intent explicit=new Intent(i);
        ComponentName cn=
                new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                        resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);

        explicit.setComponent(cn);
        ctxt.sendBroadcast(explicit);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i get data ??