# How to send BroadCast in Oreo?

Tags: android

This is my class where am getting Notification from server->

```
 public class GCMListener_Service extends GcmListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    Intent notificationReceived = new Intent("com.example.mypackage”);
    notificationReceived.putExtra(“key", fromWhere);
    sendBroadcast(notificationReceived);
    }
    }
```

this i have declared in AndroidManifiestfile:

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.pushnotification.GCMListener_Service"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

here i am trying to get Notification :

```
public class PushMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Timber.d("Received push notification”);
}
}
```

here is my receiver in AndroidManifiest file->

```
<receiver
    android:name=".notification.PushMessageReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.mobile.pushnotification.notificationReceived" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

using given code below android 8 (oreo )  it working fine i am getting and receive notification message in PushMessageReceiver class in onReceive method but in android i am unable to get notification unable to send broadcast can any one please suggest me how to send broad cast in Android O .

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015332/receiver-stopped-receiving-in-oreo

Comment: you now need to register your receiver in application class and also call it using the application class. Do not register your broadcast in your manifest file anymore. :)

Comment: @Umair thanx can you suggest some example

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki i dont have Context  in GCMListener_Service class

Comment: @AnilThakur I have posted an example code as an answer please check if it helps you get what you are trying to do. This broadcast is about checking internet connectivity you can modify it according to your requirements.

Comment: add channel id https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: @KishanViramgama channel id i will but first i need to register Receiver  to receive message

Answer (score 1):

In your `Application` class register and unRegister class like this:

```
    public class YourProjectApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
   private static YourProjectApplication sInstance;



    public static YourProjectApplication getInstance() {
            return sInstance;

        }

     @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
        }

         public void registerInternetConnectivityBroadCast(){
                IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
                registerReceiver(appInternetStatus, intentFilter);

        }

        public void unSetConnectivityListener(AppInternetStatus.InternetConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(appInternetStatus);
            }catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                AppInternetStatus.internetConnectivityReceiverListener = listener;
            }catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And then in your `mainActivity` class (which can also be your base class) call your broadcast `receiver` like this:

```
 getInstance().registerBroadCast();
 getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
```

And in order to unregister your notification. In your `onPause()` method of your main activity class :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause(); 
    getInstance().unSetConnectivityListener(null);
}
```

Comment: thanx wait let me check \

Comment: no coz i dont know how to register GCMListener_Service register and unregister  in Application Class

Comment: @AnilThakur check my edited answer it maybe help you understand how to implement it.